# Abandoning audio focus does not resume music streaming for other apps

Tags: android, audio, android-audiomanager, audio-player, android-music-player

I'm working on an app allowing users to watch videos. When they open a video to watch, I call:

```
AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager)getContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
mAudioManager.requestAudioFocus(this, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
```

This stops playback from any other apps streaming music at the time. I've tested with Play Music, Spotify, Soundcloud, etc and they all stop music playback at this point.

When the user is done watching a video, I call

```
mAudioManager.abandonAudioFocus(this);
```

but the app that was streaming music and previously paused does not resume streaming music. How can I get this to work?

I've tried doing `AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN` and `AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT`. Everything I've read on Stack Overflow just says I just need to release the audio manager. This seems so simple, but I can't figure it out. I want the functionality to be similar to how Instagram pauses and resumes music when you view a video.

Answer (score 2):

As you are requesting the complete 'AUDIO_FOCUS', the external application has to hit the play button to request the 'AUDIO_FOCUS' back. Just because your application has gained the 'AUDIO_FOCUS' and then abandoned it, this wouldn't resume the previous music/video which was being played.

The only way to overcome this would be to rethink the requirement of the application. Therefore, you can request temporary audio focus, i.e. AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT (or AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK depending on whether or not you think it's ok for other audio to keep playing in the background at a lower volume).

```
int requestAudioFocusResult = audioManager.requestAudioFocus(TimeWhisperService.this, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT_MAY_DUCK);
if(requestAudioFocusResult == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN) {
    //ACCESS GRANTED
}
```