Flutter: How to resume audio playing in other apps on android
Issue
I am using just_audio to play audio in my app, along with audio_session. When my app plays audio, I want audio of other apps to stop or duck, and resume/unduck when my apps stops audio.
Current code
This is how I have currently figured audio_session:
final session = await AudioSession.instance;
await session.configure(AudioSessionConfiguration(
    androidAudioFocusGainType: AndroidAudioFocusGainType.gainTransientMayDuck,
    androidWillPauseWhenDucked: false,
));

This is how I play audio:
AudioPlayer activePlayer = AudioPlayer(handleInterruptions: true);
await activePlayer.setAndroidAudioAttributes(AndroidAudioAttributes(
      usage: AndroidAudioUsage.alarm,
      contentType: AndroidAudioContentType.music,
    ));
await activePlayer.setLoopMode(loopMode);
await activePlayer.setAudioSource(AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse(ringtoneUri)));
await activePlayer.setVolume(volume);

// Other apps audio should stop/duck here
activePlayer?.play();

...

// Other apps audio should resume/unduck here
await activePlayer?.stop();

Current Behavior
Other app's audio does get ducked (reduced in volume) on play() but it doesn't get unducked (back to normal volume) on stop(). Tried this with multiple other apps.
Edit: Seems like the other app gains focus when my app gets closed. So that means I need to call something other than stop() to release focus from my app?
What am I doing wrong here?
Device Info
I am currently testing on an Android 14 (Google APIs) emulator. But get same behavior on Android 13 devices. Haven't tested on older devices yet.

This is probably not really a Flutter but a general Android related problem. My guess is you need a special permission in your manifest for this. Try googling your problem for android apps in gerneal

@Thomas I have looked at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42517627/abandoning-audio-focus-does-not-resume-music-streaming-for-other-apps, which seems to be pretty much my issue. The answer mentions to use 'GAIN_TRANSIENT', which I'm already doing. So I was thinking maybe this has to do with something wrong I'm doing with the flutter plugin.

the referenced question states that there other audio playback stops when the app starts playing. you mentioned that that isn't the case for you. so it is probably something else

@Thomas I do say exactly that: "I want audio of other apps to stop or duck, and resume/unduck when my apps stops audio. ... Other app's audio does get ducked (reduced in volume) on play() but it doesn't get unducked (back to normal volume) on stop()." So yes, this is my issue.

you wrote that other apps  get (reduced in volume) which is different from getting their playback stopped

Oh ok. Correct me if I'm wrong but I think that both ducking and stopping refers to variations the same behavior. What the other apps does is defined by the AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN type and how the other app handles this change of focus. In my case, I'm passing AndroidAudioFocusGainType.gainTransientMayDuck so the other app should duck, rather than stop. So saying stop/duck is interchangeable for the purposes of this discussion. The answer in the other question even mentions this, so I still think this is the same issue. But do correct me If I'm wrong.

Ah, ok, then I misunderstood your original intention. Did you see the different handling in different Android versions https://developer.android.com/media/optimize/audio-focus

@Thomas Thanks, I did a thorough read of that and I think I did get it to work. I went through the source code of this library and turns out, just_audio was never abandoning focus, like that doc page is saying should happen. I don't know if its by design or a bug, but I called 'AudioSession.instance.setActive(false)' manually after calling 'stop' and now its working.

awesome, best to file a ticket on the just_audio repository so that they can clarify this in their docs or fix the bug. In general, whenever something that is using hardware of your phone doesn't work, check the native docs on that API.

I don't know if its by design, a bug or due to something wrong I am doing, but just_audio never abandons audio focus automatically. You have to call it yourself through audio_session by calling session.setActive(false).
AudioPlayer activePlayer = AudioPlayer(handleInterruptions: true);
await activePlayer.setAndroidAudioAttributes(AndroidAudioAttributes(
      usage: AndroidAudioUsage.alarm,
      contentType: AndroidAudioContentType.music,
    ));
await activePlayer.setLoopMode(loopMode);
await activePlayer.setAudioSource(AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse(ringtoneUri)));
await activePlayer.setVolume(volume);

// Other apps audio should stop/duck here
await activePlayer?.play();

...

// Other apps audio should resume/unduck here
await activePlayer?.stop();
final session = await AudioSession.instance;
await session.setActive(false); // <-- Need to call this after audio stops

